# Codeigniter custom callback returns message wrapped in paragraph

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, callback

I am using a custom callback in codeigniter and I have a custom error message:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('_is_startdate_first', 'The start date must be first');
```

When the error message is returned, it is wrapped in '< p>' marks:

```
<p>The start date must be first</p>
```

Anyone else have this problem? Would prefer not to change the codeigniter system files if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the markup that wraps your messages using [`set_error_delimiters()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters):

**Changes delimiters for all calls to `set_message()`**

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

**Change delimiters on a per-call basis**

```
<?php echo form_error('field name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the codeigniter docs :

> By default, the Form Validation class adds a paragraph tag (< p >) around each error message shown. You can either change these delimiters globally or individually.

To set your own markup:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

**[Source](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters)**